# DNS Hijacking or just censorship?

Tags: networking, dns

I go to a school where the internet is censored by Fortiguard. My school just upgraded their system, and I believe there is some sort of DNS hijacking involved.

Whenever I try to change my DNS resolver to Google's (8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4) or even Level3's (4.2.2.2), webpages do not load, and accessing Google or any other website through a browser shows up an error just as if I did not have an internet connection. This even happens on non-SSL websites.

Websites only load when I use the default DNS provided by the router (?), in which the DNS resolver's IP starts with 127, so I believe that is a local address.

So, is this DNS Hijacking, or some other practice of censorship? Also, how may I circumvent this?

Comment: They're probably just blocking well-known DNS services, or blocking all DNs requests going outside the network.  It's their network, you're using it, so they get to decide where you can go.  We won't help you circumvent those choices, so you'll have to speak to your school's IT, and/or go get your own personal Internet connection.

Comment: I believe if you are in China, they also control DNS so they can prevent accessing the location of IPs.  Their workaround for the most part, is to use a VPN service, which pipes all your IP traffic through VPN.  This VPN service also provides DNS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about circumventing network security/policies at an institution.

Answer (score 2):

Schools and other organizations often block DNS requests (TCP port 53) outside their networks so that only the internally available DNS servers can be queried.

Usually they are required to do so to avoid showing illegal or explicit content via the school's network and thus block DNS requests.